# check date in table and update on condition in JS stored proc snowflake

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to create a stored proc in snowflake which checks if the 1st of the month is a bank holiday or a weekend, and updates it to the next working day. it seems to be getting stuck in a loop. I have the bank holidays stored in a table so I want to check if the date matches any values in that table and if it does, to take the next working day.

```
create or replace procedure check_dt(run_dt DATE)
    returns string
    language javascript
    execute as caller
    as

    $$

    function batch_date(ts){

      var a = new Date(ts);
      var dt = new Date(a.setDate(1));
      var flag = false;
      
       while(flag==false){
            var sql_stment = `select 1 from calender where bh_date = date'` + dt.toLocaleDateString() + `'`;
            var result = snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_stment});

                while(result.next()){
                    if(result.getColumnValue(1) == 1){
                        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);    
                    }
                    else if (dt.getDay() == 0){
                        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
                    }
                    else if(dt.getDay() == 6){
                        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 2);
                    }
                    else{
                      flag = true;
                      break;
                    }   
                }
    }
       
 
    
    var batch_dt = batch_date(RUN_DT);
    
    return batch_dt;
    $$;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realised by using the result.next() if the date doesn't exist in the table it never reaches the clause to update the flag, so ends in an infinite loop. the below has fixed my problem. By using row count instead, if no values are present it will continue through the if-else statement

```
create or replace procedure check_dt(run_dt DATE)
    returns string
    language javascript
    execute as caller
    as

    $$

    function batch_date(ts){

      var a = new Date(ts);
      var dt = new Date(a.setDate(1));
      var flag = false;
      
       while(flag==false){
            var sql_stment = `select 1 from calender where bh_date = date'` + dt.toLocaleDateString() + `'`;
            var result = snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_stment});

                
            if(result.getRowCount() > 0){
                dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);    
            }
            else if (dt.getDay() == 0){
                dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
            }
            else if(dt.getDay() == 6){
                dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 2);
            }
            else{
                flag = true;
            }   
                
    }
       
 
    
    var batch_dt = batch_date(RUN_DT);
    
    return batch_dt;
    $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never exiting the outer loop. You can see that by removing the code from the loops to simplify:

```
   while(flag==false){

            while(result.next()){
                  ...
                  break; 
            }
   }
```

The `break` statement will break out of the inner loop only. There's no break statement for the outer loop. There's also no line changing the value of the `flag` variable.

Comment: Sorry I missed out updating the flag, have edited the post now. Will the update of the flag not break the outer loop? or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Not updating the `flag` to true will form an infinite loop. When it's time to update it is up to your code. It's hard to tell when it's time to update that variable without a look at the data.

Comment: I want to update it in the final condition where the date isn't a bank holiday or a weekend day